# Why this avatarURL() didn't work on discordjs?

Tags: discord, discord.js

So i want to make greetings card, when someone join it will send the information about username etc, everything work great, but not with the `.setThumbnail(member.avatarURL())` i have no idea why it didnt work.

this is my full code

```
// ---- GREETINGS ----
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    const exampleEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle('Wellcome to the server :hatching_chick: ')
    .setDescription(`Hello <@${member.id}> don't forget to register ^^`)
    .setThumbnail(member.avatarURL())
    .setFooter({ text: "Please read pinned messages",
    iconURL: 'https://s3.getstickerpack.com/8c0f922eae5097'});
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('981582630317338656').send({ embeds: [exampleEmbed] });
});
```

Comment: If the member has a no avatar picture (has a default Discord avatar) `avatarURL()` will return null. Use `displayAvatarURL()` to handle default avatars.

Answer (score 0):

i use `.setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL())` thank you @Elitezen